# Python 3.7.4 function open() does not open files in pycharm

Tags: pycharm, python-3.7

Environment: Windows 10
Programm i work in: Pycharm (latest version)

If i write this code:

```
open("L:\\Python\\Projecten\\windowsfiles\\testopenfile.txt", "r")
```

But if i run the code nothing happens.
I tried the same with this by putting the file by this but nothing happened

```
open("testopenfile.txt", "r")
```

No syntax erros. just: Process finished with exit code 0
But no file game up.
I tried on a different computer. same result
I tried with a different text file, or even a picture which is .jpg, nothing happens.
what do i do wrong?
Do i need to import a module befor i can use this function:

```
open()
```

On every website i look, this is the way to do it. 
On 1 of the computers i tried this, i got an error from windows defender.
So i just turned the entire firewall off, after that. no result.
I am the full administrator on that directory.

I tried to simplify by putting the files in other directories lik this, 
but it also did not work

```
open("L:\\Python\\testopenfile.txt")
open("L:\\testopenfile.txt")
```

To test if i really have the proper permissions, i tried to create a file:

```
f = open("myfile.txt", "x")
```

Immediately the file was created in the pycharm project directory

SOLUTION:

```
# Read from .txt file whithin Python command line interface
# Files can be opened with the open statement.
file = open("L:\\Python\\Projecten\\windowsfiles\\testopenfile.txt","r")
contentfile = file.read()
print(contentfile)
# Files should always be closed after use.
file.close()

# Open files via standard programm Like files with extension .txt via 
notepad, .jpg via windows fotos.
import webbrowser
webbrowser.open("L:\\Python\\Projecten\\windowsfiles\\testopenfile.txt","r")
webbrowser.open("L:\\Python\\Projecten\\windowsfiles\\testopenfile.txt","r")
```

Comment: What exactly you are trying to achieve. If its only reading, then its correct. If you want to open file for writing, oyu need to put " r+" instead of only "r"

Comment: i work with pycharm. I just want to open a file to read it. In this case a .txt file. But any file does not work.

Comment: doing `open()` just creates a file-object to be used. If you want to read the contents, you need to `read()`

Comment: What are you doing after the call to `open`? Please include a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and explain what you expect to happen. Are you perhaps expecting your text file to open up in NotePad or something? What does "But no file came up" mean?

Comment: Have a quick read at the first [working with files](https://realpython.com/working-with-files-in-python/) tutorial I found on Google

Comment: Thank you for pointing me in to the right direction. 
1. I thought that by open() the file should open without using read()
2. I also thought that the .txt file should be opening in notepad instead of displaying the content in python console

I now read some text online and fixed all my problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> `open("L:\\Python\\Projecten\\windowsfiles\\testopenfile.txt", "r"`
>
> No syntax erros. just: Process finished with exit code 0

The `open()` function just returns a file object. Since you didn't do anything with the open file, your code finishes executing and ends with status 0 (meaning no error).

To see the file's content in your console, you could call the file's `read()` method to read it into memory, and then use the `print()` function to send it to standard output.

Also, since file objects support the context management protocol, you can use them inside a `with` statement, and the file will be closed automatically.

So, to simplify the solution you posted, you could just do:

```
my_file = 'L:/Python/Projecten/windowsfiles/testopenfile.txt'
with open(my_file) as f:
    print(f.read())
```

Comment: I also tried your solution, It works great. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Solution thanks to your fine critics:

```
# Read from .txt file whithin Python command line interface
# Files can be opened with the open statement.
file = open("L:\\Python\\Projecten\\windowsfiles\\testopenfile.txt","r")
contentfile = file.read()
print(contentfile)
# Files should always be closed after use.
file.close()

# Open files via standard programm Like files with extension .txt via 
notepad, .jpg via windows fotos.
import webbrowser
webbrowser.open("L:\\Python\\Projecten\\windowsfiles\\testopenfile.txt","r")
webbrowser.open("L:\\Python\\Projecten\\windowsfiles\\testopenfile.txt","r")
```